# Duplicate and copy based on a range of data dynamically

Tags: excel, copy, row

I found how to duplicate but not to duplicate and copy based on a range of data and when that data changes copy the first line and insert the data

I have a set of child sku's that have no parent sku and I am trying to figure out the best way to insert the parent SKU above the child SKU.

This is a sample of my data with the line inserted the way I need it:

```
36377-CSG/PDB-46    36377CSG/PDB46  ABC Brand   ABC Product     [S]Size=34,[S]Color=Cobblestone Grey/ Peacoat Dark Blue 36377
36377-CSG/PDB-46    36377CSG/PDB46  ABC Brand   ABC Product     [S]Size=34,[S]Color=Cobblestone Grey/ Peacoat Dark Blue 36377
36377-AG/BL-46      36377AG/BL46    ABC Brand   ABC Product     [S]Size=34,[S]Color=Ash Grey/Black  36377
36377-AG/BL-36      36377AG/BL36    ABC Brand   ABC Product     [S]Size=24,[S]Color=Ash Grey/Black  36377
36377-AG/BL-44      36377AG/BL44    ABC Brand   ABC Product     [S]Size=32,[S]Color=Ash Grey/Black  36377
36377-CSG/PDB-44    36377CSG/PDB44  ABC Brand   ABC Product     [S]Size=32,[S]Color=Cobblestone Grey/ Peacoat Dark Blue 36377
36377-CSG/PDB-34    36377CSG/PDB34  ABC Brand   ABC Product     [S]Size=22,[S]Color=Cobblestone Grey/ Peacoat Dark Blue 36377
36377-AG/BL-38      36377AG/BL38    ABC Brand   ABC Product     [S]Size=26,[S]Color=Ash Grey/Black  36377
36377-AG/BL-42      36377AG/BL42    ABC Brand   ABC Product     [S]Size=30,[S]Color=Ash Grey/Black  36377
36377-CSG/PDB-40    36377CSG/PDB40  ABC Brand   ABC Product     [S]Size=28,[S]Color=Cobblestone Grey/ Peacoat Dark Blue 36377
36377-CSG/PDB-42    36377CSG/PDB42  ABC Brand   ABC Product     [S]Size=30,[S]Color=Cobblestone Grey/ Peacoat Dark Blue 36377
36377-AG/BL-40      36377AG/BL40    ABC Brand   ABC Product     [S]Size=28,[S]Color=Ash Grey/Black  36377
36377-CSG/PDB-36    36377CSG/PDB36  ABC Brand   ABC Product     [S]Size=24,[S]Color=Cobblestone Grey/ Peacoat Dark Blue 36377
36377-CSG/PDB-38    36377CSG/PDB38  ABC Brand   ABC Product     [S]Size=26,[S]Color=Cobblestone Grey/ Peacoat Dark Blue 36377
24503-PFPI-85       24503PFPI85     ABC Brand   DEF Product     [S]Size=51,[S]Color=Parfait Pink    24503
24503-PFPI-85       24503PFPI85     ABC Brand   DEF Product     [S]Size=51,[S]Color=Parfait Pink    24503
24503-SPG-95        24503SPG95      ABC Brand   DEF Product     [S]Size=57,[S]Color=Steel Grey  24503
24503-PFPI-95       24503PFPI95     ABC Brand   DEF Product     [S]Size=57,[S]Color=Parfait Pink    24503
24503-PFPI-105      24503PFPI105    ABC Brand   DEF Product     [S]Size=60,[S]Color=Parfait Pink    24503
24503-SPG-115       24503SPG115     ABC Brand   DEF Product     [S]Size=66,[S]Color=Steel Grey  24503
24503-SPG-75        24503SPG75      ABC Brand   DEF Product     [S]Size=45,[S]Color=Steel Grey  24503
24503-SPG-125       24503SPG125     ABC Brand   DEF Product     [S]Size=69,[S]Color=Steel Grey  24503
24503-SPG-85        24503SPG85      ABC Brand   DEF Product     [S]Size=51,[S]Color=Steel Grey  24503
```

[image: Sample data]

What I need is every time the SKU in column g changes is for the entire top row of that set to be copied and inserted above that set. It doesn't matter which row gets copied and inserted above as long as it is a duplicate of any of those. So for example in column G 24503 it would copy row 16, insert a new row and copy the contents of row 16 above row 16. It would do that for each new set of SKU's in column G. I do not need each line duplicated just one new line for each set. Hope that makes sense. If I can get that I have a way to paste in the parent sku's already I just need that line in each section copied and inserted (not a blank line though and it needs to be the whole row across.

Comment: Sorry Stack overflow wouldn't let me post a snip or image so it ran all the data together!

Comment: Sorry about that, I think you updated it while I was editing it.

Answer (score 0):

Full automated insertion would likely best be handled by a [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(7)) Is Nothing Then  '<~~something happened in column G
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim fPos As Long, pSku As Range
        For Each pSku In Intersect(Target, Columns(7))
            fPos = Application.Match(pSku.Value2, Columns(7), 0)
            If Application.CountIf(Columns(1), Cells(fPos, 1).Value2) = 1 Then
                With Cells(fPos, 1).Resize(1, 7)
                    .Copy
                    .Insert Shift:=xlDown
                End With
            End If
        Next pSku
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Despite my best efforts at formatting your sample data, the SKUs off the right side were still coming in as column F, not G. The code above is triggered on changes to column(7); aka column G. It is designed to survive multiple SKU insertions at once; from a Copy and Paste perhaps.